# Bluez connection on STM32MP1

Tags: bluetooth, embedded-linux

I have a VisionSOM-STM32MP1 with installed OpenSTLinux and bluez version 5.50.

I am able to find nearby devices. Using bluetoothctl I can pair with the android device.
Unfortunately when I am try to establish connection from android device it fails.

```
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 Connected: no
```

Then I try to establish connection to android device, I get:

```
[bluetooth]# connect 00:00:00:00:00:00
Attempting to connect to 00:00:00:00:00:00
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device 00:00:00:00:00:00 Connected: no
```

I also tried to do this in c program, like it is [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html) and as a result I get errno 93(Protocol not supported) after creating socket.

```
s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
if(s == -1) {
   printf("errno %d\n", errno);
   return -1;
}
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can try to get more information about your issue.

I suggest that you enable debug logging in the Bluetooth daemon. I think that you need to run the Bluez daemon with "-d" for this to work. Debug logs will be in syslog.

Then you could record a HCI log using hcidump. This will tell you what HCI commands were sent to the Controller by Bluez.